# Creating installation package in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, installation, installation-package

While Creating Installation package,
 is installing crystal reports on the deployment machine same as including it in the dependency  list of the installation package in VS 2008?

Comment: If you add a Crystal Reports prerequisite, it should install it. Otherwise, you need to make sure the dependencies are included in your installer. You can always try testing on a clean machine and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it should be installed the same version of crystal report
it should also install

```
CRRedist2008_x64.msi
CRRuntime_12_2_mlb.msi
CRRuntime_12_2_mlb.exe
```

forget which one above to be installed, you can try all